# NoMethodError: undefined method `less_config` for <Class:xy>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, sprockets

I just setup twitter-bootstrap-rails as described in [it's guide](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) and now I'm getting this error on [line 39](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/blob/master/lib/less/rails/template_handlers.rb#L39) in the `lib/less/rails/template_handlers.rb` of less-rails

#### app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 */
```

I tried to debug it and deleted everything in `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` but the error stayed.

I have `therubyracer` & `less-rails` in my Gemfile, both outside of the asset group.

**What else can I do to debug this? What could cause this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

What version of less-rails is bunlded? Also what version of twitter-bootstrap-rails. I ask because the latest bootstrap stuff uses LESS v1.3.3 syntax. I dont know about the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, but I do maintain the less-rails-bootstrap gem which is fully compatabile all the way down too less-rails, less.rb and the LESS v1.3.3 syntax in the latest bootstrap code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. less-rails was 2.2.6, less was 2.2.2. I also tried your gem but got a `could not find file twitter/bootstrap`. Unfortunately I deleted the branch now (stupid me) and I'm giving Foundation a spin. If you think it's worth it and not just a mistake on my side I could reproduce it I think. ps. If there is a problem in the asset stack debugging really sucks. :)

Comment: I think the problem was that my asset pipeline is not working correctly. I tried the static variant that comes with twitter-bootstrap-rails which also did not work. I have some more debugging information here but it's not much related to the original question https://gist.github.com/mklappstuhl/1828935c0a7574894e43